# Issue with jQuery contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue with jQuery *contains*:

**HTML**

```
<span class="tag diaTags label label-info">Teststring<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
```

**JS**

If I use

```
$('span.diaTags:contains("Teststring")').attr('name', 'test');
```

everything works fine.

If I use a var for the string,

```
var tagLabel = "Teststring"
$('span.diaTags:contains(tagLabel)').attr('name', 'test');
```

nothing happens.

Thank you for your tips.

Comment: $("span.diaTags:contains("+tagLabel+")").attr('name', 'test');

Answer (score 1):

Do proper [string/variable concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

```
var tagLabel = "Teststring"
$('span.diaTags:contains(' + tagLabel + ')').attr('name', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the string and variables

```
var tagLabel = "Teststring"
$('span.diaTags:contains('+tagLabel+')').attr('name', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.diaTags:contains("+tagLabel+")").attr('name', 'test');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Use :
$("span.diaTags:contains("+tagLabel+")").attr('name', 'test');